# Is there a difference between routers if I already have a smart hub?

Tags: smart-home

I'm moving soon, and looking into adopting a mesh network. However, I'm also interested in adding some smart home devices to my new place.

I already have a 4th gen Amazon Echo, which has Zigbee connectivity. I've looked at many different mesh routers and have a question: is there any real difference between them given I already have a smart hub? That is, if two mesh networks also work with Zigbee, will there be any difference between how my IoT network will function?

For example: I'm looking at the Amazon Eero 6. It works as a smart hub with Zigbee and built-in Alexa support. I'm also looking at the TP-Link Deco (among others), which also works as a smart hub (Zigbee) but has no native Alexa support.

Given that I'll be using my Echo as my smart hub, will there be any difference in how these routers or my network will behave? In how I'll need to setup the network or new devices?

Basically, will it matter that the Eero has Alexa and the Deco doesn't? Or will they both simply be "dumb (wireless) pipes" for my Echo to communicate with the smart devices?